# Are errors and drops a normal thing?

Tags: networking, router, tcpip

My Router ( D-Link DSL 6850U ) has a status window for the LAN which shows the following:

[image][image]

This is in contrast to the WAN statistics which show zero drops and errors.

I wanted to know:
1) Does having all those drops and errors on the LAN is a normal part of the device operation and related protocols communication process or is it something that needs fixing ?
2) If it is not as it should be - how should I proceed in debugging this and understanding what is causing this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not normal in ethernet, it would be in WiFi. The mode supported by the router are 10/100 Mbps. Could you check if you're in the 10 Mbps connection case (or a lower speed)?

Are Eth cables nearby electrical cables and/or are they in a bundle, like this? [image]

If so, the signal is destroyed either by the electrical cables, or by itself (latter case)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like less than 0.04% of your packets are dropping. It is unusual for Ethernet, but I wouldn't be too worried about it. As in, I'm not happy about more than a couple errors per hour, but I won't spend any money to fix it until it gets over half a percent. These types of errors are caused by interference on the Ethernet cable. By reducing the odds of interference or switching to better/shielded cable, you might bring these numbers down. You will probably never notice these errors as a user as software will silently re-transmit packets that error out. It is not until the error rate gets much higher that user experience gets bogged down.

More advice [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/268809/acceptable-number-of-ethernet-errors-in-a-medium-sized-environment)